# Tablesaw responsive table changing on refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design, html-table

I have a responsive table using Filament Groups Tablesaw plugin. Specifically I'm using the *swipe* option with *mini-map*.

You can view the table in question [here on this development server](http://eiado.prevision.com.au/commodity-selection/commodity-prioritisation), under the **Selection and weighting** tab. The first time it loads only the *Banana* column is visible althought there's room for other columns. Refresh the page and the table refreshes to show as many columns as can fit, which is the desired outcome.

These tables are within Drupal and more specifically a QuickTabs block. Due to the fact the table renders correctly when you go directly to the *Selection and weighting* tab, I believe the problem lies with the table being in the hidden tab.

Is it possible to trigger a refresh of the tablesaw table when the tab gains focus?

I've tried changing the `data-tablesaw-priority` attribute across the headers to no success.

I've also tried running `$("#table-520").table("refresh");` and `$('#table520').table().data("table").refresh();` from the JavaScrip console as mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040732/cant-refresh-filamentgroup-tablesaw-responsive-table-after-adding-new-rows) with no success.

I appreciate any suggestions.