# Filamentgroup's Tablesaw jQuery plugin refresh on ajax call and show Headers

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, plugins, html-table

I am trying to add a column to Tablesaw table from an ajax request. Currently I have the php set to return "" (empty - intended result is to not show the column) for th and td, if the login session is not set. If the session is set, then I return the following for th and td, respectively.

```
<th class='col-md-1'>DB Actions</th>
-----
<td>
    <div class='btn-group btn-block'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success'>Actions</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'> <span class='caret'></span> </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu' id='dbActions'>
            <li><a target='_blank' href='updateDB.html'>UPDATE Stop</a>
            </li>
            <li><a onclick='savePOV()'>SAVE POV to DB</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

I am using the following code to add the th and td (excuse the mess - assume the html the data returned on successful ajax request):

```
// Insert a column/header after the first
$('#table2 > thead > tr:nth-child(1)').children(':eq(0)').after("<th class='col-md-1'>DB Actions</th>");

// Insert data (button) into second column
$('#table2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)').children(':eq(0)').after("<td><div class='btn-group btn-block'>      <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success'>Actions</button>       <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>         <span class='caret'></span>     </button>       <ul class='dropdown-menu' id='dbActions2'>          <li><a>UPDATE Stop</a></li>         <li><a>SAVE POV to DB</a></li>      </ul>   </div></td>");
```

This works, but with some issues:

- The header for that column header does not function properly (doesn't
  show) when viewing in mobile screen size (see [demo of tablesaw plugin](https://filamentgroup.github.io/tablesaw/demo/stackonly.html) vs the current result (pic below).
- I have tried using the solution from [*this SO question*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28209612/4669619), but no change.
- The split-button functionality does not work for the inserted column (I am assuming this one can be fixed by re-binding the
  split-button to desired action).
- I cannot update the table again when sign in/sign out status changes. If it was a div which had the th or td inside, I could call
  the div by id and change the inner html based on the status, but I
  don't think I can do that.
- If there is a better way to add the column, or a way to update that column's content on demand, PLEASE let me know! :)

  - There is a way
    to refresh the content on demand by inserting the th and td (with id)
    inside html and hiding them. When ready, you can get the th/td by id
    and change it's html to ajax's response and then show the th and
    td... but I am not sure if that is a good way to do it.

*Current Result:*
[image]

*Desired Result (and split-button working)*
[image]

For some reason, [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/maxwLhey/) is not bold-ing the headers in normal view nor showing any of the headers in mobile view (although it does show on my machine), where as the [**Bootply**](http://www.codeply.com/go/G7sgv1yTxc) shows the headers, but does not seem to recording the Tablesaw jQuery plugin at all!